# Software/server recommendations

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

I currently have a request put on hold asking for gallery software recommendations.

The gentleman that put it on hold suggested that I put in the Software Rec branch.

I have had a similar request there for a year now, and have gotten no acceptable answers.

I have placed other requests on Software Rec.  In general I don't get good answers.

- Fairly low traffic exchange.
- Topics are too diverse.  Asking a webmaster for software recommendations for web servers seems a better bet than asking a bunch of assorted computer users.

I think that this forum, and indeed all the branches of SE need to reconsider the asking of tool/software recommendations.

Comment: I agree with you, but we discussed this recently.

Comment: I agree too, not being able to recommend tools is sort of like discussing operating without surgical equipment. Unfortunately it's been a difficult issue to sort out since these sites are such beacons for spam and self-promotion.

Comment: I am on-board too! I understand the spam issue and agree with that too! It is a catch-22. Generally, if I have a recommendation, I will put it into a comment after the question is closed. It is far easier to delete or hide a comment later and yet still help the OP. Today, I do not have a recommendation or I would offer it to you. Sorry. I would suggest researching and experimenting. I keep one PC that gets wiped (like Hillary does with a cloth) where I can experiment with stuff from time to time.

Comment: I have more added more detail and commentary on the the duplicate.

Comment: Of course "recently" is relative.    I realized that it has been two years. We may want to start a new discussion on this matter.   When I framed the original discussion, I didn't do a good job of it.   I hadn't created an "answer" in favor of allowing recommendations which meant that for a long time the only thing to vote on was the answer not in favor.    We also have newer, but highly involved users such as dan and closetnoc that would support some sort of experimentation.